# DataWeave 2.0 - Output an XML with multiple elements

Tags: xml, dataweave, mulesoft

With DataWeave 2.0 I can output a simple XML - the following code:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml

---
a:
b:
c: "content"
```

Would output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<a>
  <b>
    <c>content</c>
  </b>
</a>
```

But what if I want multiple elements under the `b` tag, such as:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<a>
  <b>
    <c>content</c>
    <d>dontent</d>
  </b>
</a>
```

I tried to use:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml

---
a:
b:
c: "content",
d: "dontent"
```

And I got the following error:

> Invalid input ',', expected ???

I also tried to just add `d` without the comma after `c`, but it didn't work, either.

How can it be achieved?

I couldn't find anything like it in [the documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-formats-xml) or in [the tutorial](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev-guides/how-to-tutorials/dataweave-generating-xml/). Is there a way to get the XML I want without converting from JSON or any other type?

Comment: You need to get your basics cleared. Try going through the whole [dataweave-quickstart](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-quickstart) first it will give you a good idea of dataweave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this with `++` concantentation

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
a:
b:((c: "content")++("d": "dontent"))
```

Output

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<a>
  <b>
    <c>content</c>
    <d>dontent</d>
  </b>
</a>
```

Comment: That is an unusual way to define nested objects for something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

You are not explicitly telling DataWeave the structure that you want so it surprising to even get any output at all. Use the curly braces to delimit objects. `b` is a key inside `a`, so the script should reflect that:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
{
    a: {
        b: {
            c: "content",
            d: "dontent"
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<a>
  <b>
    <c>content</c>
    <d>dontent</d>
  </b>
</a>
```